# How can I do something only after an animation has finished?

Tags: unity, animation

I'm making this 2D platform based game. Basically what I want is when the player walks into spikes (which have a "deadly" tag") it displays the animation that has the parameter of animate with the value of 3 and after that the player gets destroyed. So my question is:

- How do I build a timer or something so that the object only gets destroyed after the animation is played (with no looping)?

This is the code I'm using now:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly") {
        Die();
    }
}

void Die() {
    animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 3);
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The propper way to trigger actions in certain frames of an animation is to use Animation Events. Basically, you edit the animation, adding an "event" in the last frame, and in that event you set the "Die" function to be called without any parameter.

Take a look here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html

Also, using animation events you don't depend on timers or coroutines, and you can do a lot more than waiting for the end since you have full control on every frame.

Comment: Can you use Animation Events on imported 3D animations, or only animations created within Unity? Regardless, sounds useful

Comment: @jhocking sorry, I don't know, I've never done that. From some research, it looks like imported animations are read-only, but you can create a copy and then edit Animation Events to it. I'm not sure if the animation view works for this or if you have to add the events from a script.

Comment: The problem is this can result in some crappy control flow. It would be much better to be able to do it all inline vs having a function setting a boolean that we check in a coroutine. Creates an unneeded variable and a function that "mysteriously" gets called or at least when you just look at the code that's the way it seems.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I build like a timer or something so that the object only gets
>   destroyed after the animation is played

Do this with a coroutine, something like:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly") {
      StartCoroutine(Die());
    }
}

IEnumerator Die() {
    animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 3);
    while (animator.isPlaying) { // or whatever this property is called
        yield return null;
    }
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with coroutines, that line "yield return null" in the middle tells Unity to pause this function for a frame before picking up where it left off. So this code gets stuck in a loop until the animation stops playing.

Answer (score 0):

After combining [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=14&v=g57sD272Fz0) with the answer from @DiegoSLTS I ended up with this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameOverManager : MonoBehaviour {

  private Animator animator;

  void Awake() {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
  }

  void Update () {
    if (GameManager.instance.GetHealth () <= 0) {
        Debug.Log (GameManager.instance.GetHealth ());
        animator.SetTrigger("GameOver");
    }
  }

  public void GameOverTriggered() {
    Debug.Log ("Game Over Triggered");
    Time.timeScale = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little late, but if someone will need to know, you can add events for Unity animations
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html

as well for imported Animation clips
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationEventsOnImportedClips.html
(basically the same steps, but you do them during the import/reimport of the animation/object).